# How to resolve: disconnected: not connected to DevTools (failed to check if window was closed: disconnected: not connected to DevTools)

Tags: javascript, automation, appium, webdriver-io, devtools

I am using webdriverio/appium (javascript) to test hybrid app (React app for Android / iOS):

```
 "webdriverio": "^8.22.0"
 "appium": "^2.2.1",
```

During testing I need to close and launch app, previously I have used:

```
 await driver.closeApp();
 await driver.launchApp();
```

Recently I noticed that this methods become deprecated and another approach is suggested:

```
appPackage = 'com.xxx.yyy'

await driver.execute('mobile: terminateApp', { appId: `${constants.appPackage}` });

const platform = await driver.capabilities['platformName'];
if (platform === 'Android') {
      await driver.execute('mobile: activateApp', { appId: `${constants.appPackage}` }); // android
    } else {
      await driver.execute('mobile: launchApp', { appId: `${constants.appPackage}` }); // ios
    }

await driver.switchContext(appContext);
```

When start tests it automatically launch app and start execution, but when I need to rerun app (using approach above) I getting an error:

> An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: disconnected: not connected to DevTools (failed to check if window was closed: disconnected: not connected to DevTools)

The solution:

add

```
 await driver.reloadSession();
```

after rerun app

```
if (platform === 'Android') {
      await driver.execute('mobile: activateApp', { appId: `${constants.appPackage}` }); // android
    } else {
      await driver.execute('mobile: launchApp', { appId: `${constants.appPackage}` }); // ios
    }

    await driver.reloadSession();

    await this.switchToContext('WEBVIEW_com.xxx.yyy');
```